# virtualbox guest (win 7) on linuxmint host (17.2) menu and taskbar inactive in full screen

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, linux-mint, taskbar, kde

I am running virtualbox 5.02 on a linuxmint host (kde desktop, linuxmint 17.2) and running a windows guest (win 7).

After some time of using this guest (around one month) the windows 7 menu and taskbar stopped responding to mouse clic in full screen mode, while in "seamless mode", where only taskbar and menu of guest is displayed on my linux desktop, both win 7 menu and taskbar are funcionning normally.

below the informations given as "session information" (title roughly translated from french)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Général
Nom : seven$
Type d'OS : Windows 7 (64-bit)
 ￼
Système 
Mémoire vive : 2048 Mo 
Nombre de processeurs : 1 
Temps processeur alloué: 100%
Ordre d'amorçage : Disquette, Optical, Disque dur
VT-x/AMD-V : Activé
Pagination imbriquée : Activée
Paravirtualization Interface: Legacy
 ￼
Affichage
Mémoire vidéo : 256 Mo 
Accélération 3D : Activée
Accélération 2D : Activée
Serveur du bureau à distance (RDP): Désactivé

￼
Stockage
Contrôleur : IDE
Maître secondaire IDE (Optical Drive):VBoxGuestAdditions.iso (56,00 Mio)
Contrôleur : SATA
Port SATA 0 : seven-disk2.vdi (Normal, 51,56 Gio)

￼
Son
Pilote hôte : PulseAudio
Contrôleur : Intel Audio HD

￼
Réseau
Carte 1 : Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (NAT)

￼
Ports séries désactivé

￼
USB
Filtres :0 (0 actif)

￼
Dossiers partagés 
Dossiers partagés: 1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

information d'exécution :
￼
Propriétés

Résolution de l'écran
1366x768x32 @0,0

VM Uptime
0d 01:29:50￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Mode du presse-papier
Bidirectionnel￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Drag and Drop Mode
Désactivé￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

VT-x/AMD-V 
Active￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Pagination imbriquée 
Active￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Exécution sans restriction
Active￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Paravirtualization Interface
Aucun￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Additions invité
4.3.30 r101610￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Guest OS Type
Windows 7 (64-bit)￼

Port du bureau à distance
Non disponible￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

￼
Statistiques du stockage

Contrôleur : IDE

  Maître secondaire IDE :

    Transferts DMA
40￼

    Transferts PIO 
205￼

    Données lues
280 576 B

    Données écrites
0 B


Contrôleur : SATA

  Port SATA 0 :

    Transferts DMA
146 723￼

    Données lues
3 067 447 296 B

    Données écrites
638 518 272 B

￼
Statistiques du réseau

Carte 1 

  Données transmise
614 938 B

  Données reçues
6 076 927 B

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i tried to restart win 7 in safe mode but after several trials i had no succes correcting this. thanks for your advice,

Answer (score 0):

as for now i just discovered that "allowing windows to cover" for kde taskbar (i was in the "autohide" configuration before) restored the win 7 host taskbar normal behavior.

i would prefer to keep the autohide, but at least i now know how to use the w7 guest normally now... (strange that in seamless mode it works with kde autohide activated)

thanks for commenting this

humpf